# DotNetCart Better Documentation

Tags: asp.net, documentation, e-commerce

I'm attempting to use the [DotNetCart](http://www.dotnetcart.com/) ecommerce module in a solution we are building. The problem i'm having is that i'm finding that the included .chm documentation is quite lacking. I've brought this up with their support dept and received no help there. My question is, is there a site or forum that is a good source of information on how to use different aspects of their API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently - there does not appear to be any better documentation than the cruddy POS that they provide.

Answer (score 1):

The developer documentation guide on their help chm file seems to be quite elaborate.  Climb down until you get to DeveloperDocumentation | dotNetCartNamespace | Classes.

Comment: Are we looking at the same .chm file? All it shows in there (all levels) is the name of the function or property for almost all objects in the model. Descriptions are almost completely non-existent. BTW...Do you work for dotnetcart?